# How can I make Xamarin Forms close open swiped views?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using SwipeView inside a CollectionView:

[image]

```
           <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfDecks}" 
                                SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="0" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <SwipeView>
                            <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <SwipeItems Mode="Reveal" SwipeBehaviorOnInvoked="Auto">
                                    <SwipeItem Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteDeckCmd, Source={x:Reference ThisPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="aa" BackgroundColor="Red" />
                                    <SwipeItem Command="{Binding BindingContext.RenameDeckCmd, Source={x:Reference ThisPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="xx" BackgroundColor="LightGray"/>
                                </SwipeItems>
                            </SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <t:DeckGridTemplate />

                        </SwipeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

When I swipe to the left it works good. But when I swipe another row the first row does not close.

So in the end if I don't go in and manually close all the swiped rows my UX looks very bad.  Is there a way I can auto close one swipe when another is run and also close a swipe when I go the next screen and return back to this screen?

Comment: You should submit this as a bug. Still it is a vaild question as there are likely workarounds.

Comment: This is not a bug, this is how the SwipeView is intended to behave. Instead of bug, you can create an enhancement request. Having said that, you can iterate through all of the swipe views inside your templates and close them by hand using `swipeView.Close();`
Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/swipeview#open-and-close-a-swipeview-programmatically

Comment: Thanks Mihail,  Do you have any idea of how this could be done in backend code.  If you can take the time to add an answer I would be pleased to accept that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SwipView** has `SwipeStarted` and `SwipeEnded` method , using them can close the previous opened item .

For example , adding `SwipeStarted` and `SwipeEnded` into **Xaml** ( [code based on the official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/) ) as follow :

```
...
<SwipeView SwipeStarted="SwipeView_SwipeStarted" SwipeEnded="SwipeView_SwipeEnded">
            <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                <SwipeItems SwipeBehaviorOnInvoked="Close"
                            Mode="Reveal">
                    <SwipeItem Text="Favorite"
                                IconImageSource="favorite.png"
                                BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.FavoriteCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                                IconImageSource="delete.png"
                                BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </SwipeItems>
            </SwipeView.LeftItems>
  ...
```

Declare a `List<SwipeView>` in the ContentPage . When invoking `SwipeEnded`, add item into `List<SwipeView>`. Later when invoking `SwipeStarted` , close and remove the previous item .

```
List<SwipeView> swipeViews { set; get; }
public VerticalListSwipeContextItemsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new MonkeysViewModel();

    swipeViews = new List<SwipeView>();
}

private void SwipeView_SwipeStarted(object sender, SwipeStartedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SwipeView_SwipeStarted");

    if(swipeViews.Count == 1)
    {
        swipeViews[0].Close();
        swipeViews.Remove(swipeViews[0]);
    }
}

private void SwipeView_SwipeEnded(object sender, SwipeEndedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SwipeView_SwipeEnded");
    swipeViews.Add(swipView);
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a short [blog](https://baseflow.com/blogs/singleswipeview-collection-xamarin) about my solution earlier. The example repo you can find [here](https://github.com/rickdijk/SwipeViewCollectionExample/tree/main/SwipeViewCollectionExample/SingleSwipeCollectionExample).

For this project, I used a simple MVVM setup, so we need at least a Model, a View and a ViewModel to work with.
I will only use SwipeViews that open up on the right side, but you can implement this solution in every way you like for the SwipeView. I would say the possibilities are countless…

#### Model

First thing I set up was the model, in this case a Person class with two properties. The IsOpen property is necessary to bind to the custom SwipeView I will explain later. I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to be able to notify the view about the IsOpen property updates.

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _isOpen;
    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get => _isOpen;
        set
        {
            if (_isOpen != value)
            {
                _isOpen = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

Simply create a list of Persons as a source for the CollectionView. The DeleteCommand handles the SwipeView Delete button that shows up when swiping the item to the left. The OpenItemChangedCommand sets the IsOpen property of any other Person item, that is not the last swiped Person item, to false.
OnPropertyChanged() is needed to update the page when an item is deleted from the list.

```
public class SwipeViewCollectionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public SwipeViewCollectionViewModel()
      {
          Persons = new List<Person>
          {
              new Person { Name =  "Albert"},
              new Person { Name =  "Burak"},
              new Person { Name =  "Conny"},
              new Person { Name =  "Dolly"},
              new Person { Name =  "Erik"},
          };
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private List<Person> _persons;
      public List<Person> Persons
      {
          get => _persons;
          set
          {
              if (_persons != value)
              {
                  _persons = value;
                  OnPropertyChanged();
              }
          }
      }

      private Command<Person> _deletePersonCommand;
      public Command<Person> DeletePersonCommand => _deletePersonCommand ??= new Command<Person>((person) => Persons.Remove(person));

      private Command<Person> _openItemChangedCommand;
      public Command<Person> OpenItemChangedCommand => _openItemChangedCommand ??= new Command<Person>(ChangeOpenPersonItem);
      private void ChangeOpenPersonItem(Person swipedPersonItem)
      {
          if (swipedPersonItem != null && swipedPersonItem.IsOpen)
          {
              if (Persons.Count < 2 || Persons.Select(x => x.IsOpen).Count() < 2)
                  return;

              foreach (var person in Persons.Where(x => x != swipedPersonItem && x.IsOpen))
              {
                  person.IsOpen = false;
              }
          }
      }

      private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
  }
```

#### Custom SwipeView

In order to get the solution working, we need to extend the existing SwipeView with some properties of our own. In the official documentation for SwipeView, I have already seen a bindable property IsOpen, but in the current stable Xamarin version, you’re not yet able to use it. In this case I created a bindable IsOpen property that will be bound to the IsOpen property in the Person model. When that property changes, the Command will be executed. Also make sure to set the BindingMode to TwoWay, since we need to be able to update both the View and the ViewModel in both ways.

The SwipeView gives us the ability to subscribe to the SwipeEnded event. With the SwipeEndedEventArgs we’re able to check if the SwipeView is open when the swipe gesture has ended. This is the key of success to this implementation: if the SwipeView is open, the IsOpen property will be updated. This will update the IsOpen property for the swiped Person item AND will execute the command to make sure all other Person items in the list will have the IsOpen property set to false.

```
public class CustomSwipeView : SwipeView, IDisposable
{
    public CustomSwipeView()
    {
        SwipeEnded += CustomSwipeView_SwipeEnded;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsOpenProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(IsOpen),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(CustomSwipeView),
        false,
        BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: IsOpenPropertyChanged);

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomSwipeView), null);
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(CommandParameter), typeof(object), typeof(CustomSwipeView), null);
    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get => GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SwipeEnded -= CustomSwipeView_SwipeEnded;
    }

    private static void IsOpenPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (!(bindable is CustomSwipeView control) || !(oldValue is bool wasOpen) || !(newValue is bool isOpen))
            return;

        if (!wasOpen)
            return;

        if (!isOpen)
            control.Close();
    }

    private void CustomSwipeView_SwipeEnded(object sender, SwipeEndedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsOpen && Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter))
        {
            IsOpen = true;
            Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
        }
    }
}
```

#### CollectionView

Last but not least, we need to create the page with the CollectionView. I used relative binding to be able to bind to the ViewModel from a DataTemplate. The model itself is bound as a CommandParameter to be able to update or delete the model from the list. Make sure to bind the Person.IsOpen property to the CustomSwipeView.IsOpen property.

```
<CollectionView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
    SelectionMode="None">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout
            Orientation="Vertical"
            ItemSpacing="10"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView>
                <views:CustomSwipeView
                    Margin="8"
                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:SwipeViewCollectionViewModel}}, Path=OpenItemChangedCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                    IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}">
                    <views:CustomSwipeView.RightItems>
                        <SwipeItems>
                            <SwipeItemView
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:SwipeViewCollectionViewModel}}, Path=DeletePersonCommand}">
                                <Frame
                                    HasShadow="False"
                                    BackgroundColor="Red">
                                    <Label Text="Delete" TextColor="White"/>
                                </Frame>
                            </SwipeItemView>
                        </SwipeItems>
                    </views:CustomSwipeView.RightItems>
                    <Frame
                        HasShadow="False"
                        BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Frame>
                </views:CustomSwipeView>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

This is my solution, I bet there are many other solutions. If you have one, let me know!
I created an [example repo](https://github.com/rickdijk/SwipeViewCollectionExample/tree/main/SwipeViewCollectionExample/SingleSwipeCollectionExample) for everyone to refer to. You can also find me on Twitter ([@rickavdijk](https://twitter.com/rickavdijk)) and [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/rickvdijk/).

Comment: Please don't use an external git repository to show your code, as it's not guaranteed to be static, not always accessible by all readers, and not immediately obvious where to find the relevant code. Instead, please [edit] your answer to include code examples that are relevant to the question in the answer itself (using [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), no images of code please!).

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut you're right, I uploaded the code examples here

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to my reputation, I can’t write a comment yet. But in the wonderful solution above, which I used (thanks), there is an error.

```
 private void SwipeView_SwipeEnded(object sender, SwipeEndedEventArgs e)


{
 var sw = (SwipeView)sender;
 swipeViews.Add(sw);


}
```